# I cannot get this html code to display what i want

Tags: javascript, html

So i was making a thing for a video game. All i want it to do for right now is when you click the button it should choose a random name from the list and display it under the button (i will be adding basically the same thing but change whats in the list) but i dn't know how to get it to show on the screen. Here is my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF=8">
        <title>Skull picker v3.2</title>
        <style>
            *{padding:0;margin:0}
            canvas {background:#ffffff;display:block;margin:0 auto}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>The Halo Skull Picker</h1>
        <p>This is the first version of the Halo skull picker. Click the button below and it *should* give you a random selection of skulls to enable, if nothing shows up that would be no skulls</p>
        <p>Also as I further inprove this there will be options for every halo game</p>

        <button onclick="myFunction()">MCC Halo: CE Anniversary</button>

        <script>
        var words = ['Anger',
        'Black Eye',
        'Blind',
        'Catch',
        'Eye Patch',
        'Famine',
        'Fog',
        'Foreign',
        'Iron',
        'Mythic',
        'Recession',
        'Thats just...Wrong',
        'Thunderstorm',
        'Tough luck',
        'Bandanna',
        'Boom',
        'Ghost',
        'Grunt Birthday Party',
        'Grunt Funeral',
        'Malfunction',
        'Pinata',
        'Sputnik',
        ];

        function myFunction() {
            return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
        }

        for(var x=0; x<20, x++)
            console.log(randomword(words));



        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
var words = ['Anger',
        'Black Eye',
        'Blind',
        'Catch',
        'Eye Patch',
        'Famine',
        'Fog',
        'Foreign',
        'Iron',
        'Mythic',
        'Recession',
        'Thats just...Wrong',
        'Thunderstorm',
        'Tough luck',
        'Bandanna',
        'Boom',
        'Ghost',
        'Grunt Birthday Party',
        'Grunt Funeral',
        'Malfunction',
        'Pinata',
        'Sputnik',
        ];

        function myFunction() {
           let idx =  Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
           
           var element=document.getElementById('here');
            console.log(words[idx]);
            element.innerHTML=words[idx];
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF=8">
        <title>Skull picker v3.2</title>
        <style>
            *{padding:0;margin:0}
            canvas {background:#ffffff;display:block;margin:0 auto}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>The Halo Skull Picker</h1>
        <p>This is the first version of the Halo skull picker. Click the button below and it *should* give you a random selection of skulls to enable, if nothing shows up that would be no skulls</p>
        <p>Also as I further inprove this there will be options for every halo game</p>

        <button onclick="myFunction()">MCC Halo: CE Anniversary</button>

        <div id='here'></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, the only thing now is that here when i hit run code snipet it works fine, i really like the way it keeps the last answer it chose on the screen. I just need help getting it to work in my .html file. I tried putting it in there, even copying and pasting but it wont work in there. Sorry by the way for any headache i am not very good at coding and i cant seem to find a good way to learn in depth

Comment: try it now, I just updated the answer.  I was writing out to the console not the web page.  Now I'm doing both.  do you know how to view the console.log?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a container, or any other tag to display the word.
Then, query from your script and provide a random word to the innerHTML.

```js
let words = [
    `random`,
    `words`,
    `on`,
    `demand`
];

const wordDisplay = document.querySelector("#word-display");

const randomIndex = max => Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
const getRandom = arr => arr[randomIndex(arr.length)];

const showWord = () => {
    const word = getRandom(words);
    wordDisplay.innerHTML = word;
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="./script.js" defer></script>
        <title>Test purposes</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>The Halo Skull Picker</h1>
        <p>This is the first version of the Halo skull picker. Click the button below and it *should* give you a random selection of skulls to enable, if nothing shows up that would be no skulls</p>
        <p>Also as I further inprove this there will be options for every halo game</p>

        <button onclick="showWord()">MCC Halo: CE Anniversary</button>
        <div id="word-display"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Two things.
Important to defer the script run to be able to fetch the HTML element after rendering it.
I coded the script as ES6.
This is how you could code as ES5:

```
var words = [
    'random',
    'words',
    'on',
    'demand'
]

var wordDisplay = document.querySelector("#word-display");

function randomIndex(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
} 
function getRandom(arr) {
    return arr[randomIndex(arr.length)];
} 

function showWord() {
    var word = getRandom(words);
    wordDisplay.innerHTML = word;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried this but since i am not very good i cant seem to get it to work, even when i copy and paste it.

Comment: What's the issue, then?

Comment: Well i want to make this in a html file i can send my friend or host from my ip address. On this website the code works when i click the run code snipet but when i put in my file it wont work

Comment: Make sure your js file is in the same directory as the html one and it is called `script.js` to satisfy the `source` of the `script` tag inside the HTML headers

Comment: Im sorry but i have no clue really by that. I get the just but what exactly am i putting into the script.js file and what in the code is referencing that?

Comment: In HTML, `script` tag contains the Javascript code to be run by the page. To avoid large HTML files, these `script` tags accept a `src` (or source) attribute that points to a `.js` file, a path to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF=8">
    <title>Skull picker v3.5</title>
    <style>
        *{padding:0;margin:0}
        canvas {background:#ffffff;display:block;margin:0 auto}
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>The Halo Skull Picker</h1>
    <p>This is the first version of the Halo skull picker. Click the button below and it *should* give you a random selection of skulls to enable, if nothing shows up that would be no skulls</p>
    <p>Also as I further inprove this there will be options for every halo game</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">MCC Halo: CE Anniversary</button>
    <button onclick="myFunction1">addon test</button>
    <p id="jack"></p>

    <script>
    var words = ['Anger',
    'Black Eye',
    'Blind',
    'Catch',
    'Eye Patch',
    'Famine',
    'Fog',
    'Foreign',
    'Iron',
    'Mythic',
    'Recession',
    'Thats just...Wrong',
    'Thunderstorm',
    'Tough luck',
    'Bandanna',
    'Boom',
    'Ghost',
    'Grunt Birthday Party',
    'Grunt Funeral',
    'Malfunction',
    'Pinata',
    'Sputnik',
    ];
var words1 = ['Anger',
    'Black Eye',
    'Blind',
    'Catch',
    'Eye Patch',
    'Famine',
    'Fog',
    'Foreign',
    'Iron',
    'Mythic',
    'Recession',
    'Thats just...Wrong',
    'Thunderstorm',
    'Tough luck',
    'Bandanna',
    'Boom',
    'Ghost',
    'Grunt Birthday Party',
    'Grunt Funeral',
    'Malfunction',
    'Pinata',
    'Sputnik',
    ];
    function myFunction() {
        num = Math.floor((Math.random() * words.length));
        document.getElementById('jack').innerHTML+=words[num]+'<br>'
    }

    function myFunction1() {
        num = Math.floor((Math.random() * words1.length));
        document.getElementById('jack').innerHTML+=words1[num]+'<br>'
    }       
    </script>

</body>
```

I managed to get it to display the answer like i wanted with the help of a friend, but sadly now when i tried to copy it to a different button that has a different list it sadly didn't work with that, so first problem solved but second one is not